# Automatic hyphenation in margin notes

Tags: hyphenation, marginpar

I build a document with notes (like footnotes) on margins.
I found help on LaTeX community and now my preamble looks like that:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\footnotesize}
\newcounter{mynote}
\newcommand{\mynote}[2][0]{
\refstepcounter{mynote}
\mbox{\textsuperscript{\themynote}}
\marginnote{\mbox{\textsuperscript{\themynote}}\hspace{0pt}#2}[#1\baselineskip}
\newcommand{\mybr}{-\\}
```

Everything works pretty well except automatic hyphenation. I need to divide words manually by using `\mybr{}`.
I prefer ragged notes, but justified could be too, if automatic hyphenation works only like this.

Answer (score 15):

TeX doesn't hyphenate the first word in a paragraph. You can write a `\hspace{0pt}` before it, then TeX takes this as first word or use `lualatex` it hasn't such restriction.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{\RaggedLeft}
\renewcommand*{\raggedrightmarginnote}{\RaggedRight}
\newcommand\Marginnote[1]{\marginnote{\hspace{0pt}#1}}

\begin{document}
foo\Marginnote{Mülltonnenentsorgungsprogramm}
\end{document}
```

or with an up-to-date TeX distribution (2018) one needs only

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
    foo\marginnote{Mülltonnenentsorgungsprogramm}
\end{document}


*File List*
 scrbook.cls    2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent bas
ics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent b
asics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo    2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2018/03/30 v3.25 KOMA-Script package (type area)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
marginnote.sty    2018/08/09 v1.4b non floating margin notes for LaTeX
   babel.sty    2018/09/02 3.23 The Babel package
 ngerman.ldf    2018/03/29 v2.10 German support for babel (post-1996 orthography)
 ***********
```

Comment: Leo Liu, Herbert, thanks a lot! ragged2e works perfect!

Comment: Hm, this does not seem to work if justified text is used as proposed by the manual: `\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{}
\renewcommand*{\raggedrightmarginnote}{\Centering}
`

Comment: Works for me, too!

Answer (score 11):

This would help:

```
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{\RaggedLeft}
\renewcommand*{\raggedrightmarginnote}{\RaggedRight}
```

See manuals of `marginnote` and `ragged2e` for more information.