# Hyphenation/text wrapping in \parbox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, xetex, boxes, hyphenation

I have a `\parbox` with some text. The text should be wrapped as normal, but it doesn't seam to work, while the words wrap in normal text:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,parskip]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}

\begin{document}
\parbox[t]{24mm}{Besichtigungszeiten} \parbox[t]{30mm}{10 bis 12 und\\ 14 bis 18 Uhr}\par
\parbox[t]{24mm}{Anmeldung} \parbox[t]{30mm}{10 bis 12 und 14 bis 18 Uhr}\par
\parbox[t]{24mm}{Kontakt} \parbox[t]{30mm}{Hans Wurst}\par

Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung

\parbox{70mm}{
  \begin{tabular}{p{24mm}|p{30mm}}
    Besichtigungszeiten & 10 bis 12 und\\ 14 bis 18 Uhr \\
    Anmeldung & 10 bis 12 und 14 bis 18 Uhr \\
    Kontakt & Hans Wurst \\
  \end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm using xelatex from texlive.

**edit:** Using a tabular doesn't make a difference here. Further I'm using parbox, because there might be line breaks in the values.

Comment: Wouldn't a `tabular` environment been more suited for this typesetting?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `[t]` would work with `\\ ` (the final `\\ ` is wrong for other reasons, but alignment works anyway)

Comment: lots of duplicates.  here's one: [Automatic hyphenation in margin notes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10815/579)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX does not hyphenate the first word of a paragraph, you need to add a space before. Also alignment is improved if you top-align the parboxes. never end a paragraph with `\\`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,parskip]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}

\begin{document}
\parbox[t]{24mm}{\hspace{0pt}Besichtigungszeiten}
\parbox[t]{30mm}{10 bis 12 und 14 bis 18 Uhr\strut}\\
\parbox[t]{24mm}{Anmeldung}
\parbox[t]{30mm}{10 bis 12 und 14 bis 18 Uhr\strut}\\
\parbox[t]{24mm}{Kontakt} \parbox{30mm}{Hans Wurst}

Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung Besichtigungszeiten Anmeldung
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, you win.  Not that I expected any other outcome. +1 and I'll delete my comments.

Comment: So the statement “TeX does not hyphenate the first word of a paragraph” combined with `\hspace{0pt}` was the solution. Why is it bad to and a paragraph with `\\`? I'm generating the entries with a for-loop.

Comment: ending a paragraph with `\\ ` forces a linebreak before the paragraph end and then a spurious white line after the paragraph that has no text in it but makes a underfull box badness 10000 warning. Note it looks like vertical space but it is not (and is not discarded at a page break) it is a false additional line of the paragraph

Comment: @white_gecko TeX does not format a paragraph on the fly, but only when the paragraph is complete does it perform its paragraph-setting magic.  Ending it with a ``\\`` interrupts that process.  This notion pops up frequently in LaTeX constructions.  For example, `{\centering Am I centered?}` will not be centered, but `{\centering Am I centered?\par}` will be centered, because ending the paragraph was needed for the centering magic to occur.