# Vertical spacing between parboxes

Tags: spacing, boxes

I'm using `\parbox` for creating a flexible table-like structure of paragraphs as in the following minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}                % language package
\setmainlanguage{english}               % select language for polyglossia
\begin{document}
  \parbox{20mm}{Some Text in the first column} \parbox{30mm}{Some Text in the second column}\par
  \parbox{20mm}{Some Text in the first column} \parbox{30mm}{Some Text in the second column}\par
  \parbox{20mm}{Some Text in the first column} \parbox{30mm}{Some Text in the second column}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

The line spacing within the parboxes is as desired, but the vertical spacing between the parboxes seams to be somehow close to `0pt`. Which is the correct length to check and adjust here to get a space between the parboxes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a `\strut` to the **beginning and end** of the `\parbox`.  The top and bottom of the `\parbox` are flush-fitting to the text, so if you need the normal dead-zone space above and below the line, a `\strut` extends the text row vertically to the extent allocated by normal line spacing.

Placing a flush-fitting box around each `\parbox` demonstrates the problem with the unstrutted `\parbox`es, as shown here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}                % language package
%\setmainlanguage{english}               % select language for polyglossia
\let\svparbox\parbox
\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
\renewcommand\parbox[3][c]{\fbox{\svparbox[#1]{#2}{#3}}}
\begin{document}
  \parbox{20mm}{Some Text in the first column} \parbox{30mm}{Some Text in the second column}\par
  \parbox{20mm}{Some Text in the first column} \parbox{30mm}{Some Text in the second column}\par
  \parbox{20mm}{Some Text in the first column} \parbox{30mm}{Some Text in the second column}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a fix by adding a `\strut` to the beginning/end of the `\parbox`..

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}                % language package
%\setmainlanguage{english}               % select language for polyglossia
\begin{document}
  \parbox{20mm}{\strut Some Text in the first column\strut} \parbox{30mm}{\strut Some Text in the second column\strut}\par
  \parbox{20mm}{\strut Some Text in the first column\strut} \parbox{30mm}{\strut Some Text in the second column\strut}\par
  \parbox{20mm}{\strut Some Text in the first column\strut} \parbox{30mm}{\strut Some Text in the second column\strut}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you *always* wanted to strut your `\parbox`es, you could redefine it:

```
\let\svparbox\parbox
\renewcommand\parbox[3][c]{\svparbox[#1]{#2}{\strut#3\strut}}
```

Safer though, would be to create your own macro:

```
\newcommand\sparbox[3][c]{\parbox[#1]{#2}{\strut#3\strut}}
```

Comment: It seams that I need a space before the final `\strut` to get the correct text wrapping behavior (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229026/hyphenation-text-wrapping-in-parbox).

Comment: How can I draw such a flush-fitting box?

Comment: @white_gecko  That is a good point.

Comment: @white_gecko `\let\svparbox\parbox\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\renewcommand\parbox[3][c]{\fbox{\svparbox[#1]{#2}{#3}}}`

Comment: @steven-b-segletes thanks, that seams to work, but maybe you could edit your comment, there is some hidden chat between the `b` and the `o` in the last `\svparb‌​ox`

Comment: @white_gecko  I just revised my answer to include the code.