# Right alignment of two left ragged lines

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I have two small lines of text with different width. I want flush them right keeping their left justification and the line height of previous text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

I was yet young in life, which I had begun early; but my intimacy with him was of a recent date: we had been educated at the same schools and university; but his progress through these had preceded mine, and he had been deeply initiated into what is called the world while I was in noviciate noviciate noviciate.

\hfill\vbox{\hbox{Foo}
\hbox{Foobar}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: a similar problem is addressed in this question: [Vertical spacing between parboxes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230073/579)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `tabular` with `[t]`op alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

I was yet young in life, which I had begun early; but my intimacy with him was of a recent date: we had been educated at the same schools and university; but his progress through these had preceded mine, and he had been deeply initiated into what is called the world while I was in noviciate noviciate noviciate.

\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
Foo\\
Foobar
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I upvote @HarishKumar's answer, because _that_ is the correct way of doing what you want to do.

Comment: To be fussy, with the `t` option to `tabular` you get the `\lineskip` glue, instead of `\baselineskip`, _below_ the two exceptional lines.  But probably, in a situation like this, it is not worth the effort to insist on performing the "optimal" solution (`\strut` in the preceding line, `b` option to `tabular`, then `{\offinterlineskip\par}` just after the `tabular` itself… (:-)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to put a `\strut` both at the end of the preceding text and inside the `\hbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

I was yet young in life, which I had begun early; but my intimacy with him
was of a recent date: we had been educated at the same schools and
university; but his progress through these had preceded mine, and he had
been deeply initiated into what is called the world while I was in
noviciate noviciate noviciate.\strut

\hfill\vbox{\hbox{\strut Foo}
\hbox{Foobar}}

\end{document}
```

But using primitive boxing commands in LaTeX is not recommended.