# Vertical spacing between parbox

Tags: vertical-alignment, expex, parbox

I have a running series of `parbox`es that contain interlinear glosses. Because of the `parbox` (and the gloss), there is no breaking across pages. As a result, the `parbox`es are evenly distributed vertically on the page. I do not want distribution like this. Instead, I want the `parbox`es to have a pre-defined space in between each one so that any remaining white space will accumulate at the bottom of the page (instead of in between `parbox`es). See below for a pictorial description of what I want.

EDIT: To clarify, I want consistent spacing between parboxes throughout the document (not just on a single page as per `\raggedbottom`), and I want to be able to dictate what that space is.

[image]
**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{expex}

\lingset{
    everygla=\large,
    everyglb=\scriptsize,
    everyglc=\scriptsize,
    glwordalign=center,
    glhangindent=0em,
    glrightskip=0pt,
    aboveglbskip=-0.9ex,
    aboveglcskip=-0.9ex
}

\definelingstyle{justified}{glrightskip=0pt,glspace=0.5em plus 3em minus 0.15em,everyglft=\justifying\noindent}

\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\newcommand{\swapboxes}[2]% #1 = wide text, #2 = narrow text
{\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\checkoddpage
 \ifoddpageoroneside
   \parbox[t]{.71\textwidth}{#1}\hfill\parbox[t]{.26\textwidth}{#2}%
 \else
   \parbox[t]{.26\textwidth}{#2}\hfill\parbox[t]{.71\textwidth}{#1}%
 \fi}}

\begin{document}

\swapboxes{\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. //

  \glb aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccccccccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

  \glc aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

\endgl\xe}{\exdisplay\footnotesize{Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification.} \xe}

\swapboxes{\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. //

  \glb aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

  \glc aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

\endgl\xe}{\exdisplay\footnotesize{Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification.} \xe}

\swapboxes{\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. //

  \glb aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccccccccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

  \glc aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

\endgl\xe}{\exdisplay\footnotesize{Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification.} \xe}

\swapboxes{\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. //

  \glb aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

  \glc aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

\endgl\xe}{\exdisplay\footnotesize{Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification.} \xe}

\swapboxes{\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. //

  \glb aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

  \glc aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

\endgl\xe}{\exdisplay\footnotesize{Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification.} \xe}

\swapboxes{\exdisplay\begingl
  \gla Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. //

  \glb aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

  \glc aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

\endgl\xe}{\exdisplay\footnotesize{Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification.} \xe}

\end{document}
```

I saw [this Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230073/vertical-spacing-between-parboxes) but didn't find it helpful in my case (or I just didn't understand it well enough).

Comment: Try using the `\raggedbottom` directive in your preamble.

Comment: What if I want tighter spacing than what `\raggedbottom` provides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Together with `\raggedbottom`, you may use `\setlength{\parskip}{...}` to adjust the height between paragraphs as you like.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{expex}
\raggedbottom
\setlength{\parskip}{-.7\baselineskip}% you can adjust the height as you prefer

\lingset{
    everygla=\large,
    everyglb=\scriptsize,
    everyglc=\scriptsize,
    glwordalign=center,
    glhangindent=0em,
    glrightskip=0pt,
    aboveglbskip=-0.9ex,
    aboveglcskip=-0.9ex
}

\definelingstyle{justified}{glrightskip=0pt,glspace=0.5em plus 3em minus 0.15em,everyglft=\justifying\noindent}

\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\newcommand{\swapboxes}[2]% #1 = wide text, #2 = narrow text
{\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\checkoddpage
        \ifoddpageoroneside
        \parbox[t]{.71\textwidth}{#1}\hfill\parbox[t]{.26\textwidth}{#2}%
        \else
        \parbox[t]{.26\textwidth}{#2}\hfill\parbox[t]{.71\textwidth}{#1}%
        \fi}}

\begin{document}

    \swapboxes{\exdisplay\begingl
        \gla Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. //

        \glb aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccccccccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

        \glc aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

        \endgl\xe}{\exdisplay\footnotesize{Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification.} \xe}

    \swapboxes{\exdisplay\begingl
        \gla Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. //

        \glb aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

        \glc aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

        \endgl\xe}{\exdisplay\footnotesize{Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification.} \xe}

    \swapboxes{\exdisplay\begingl
        \gla Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. //

        \glb aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccccccccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

        \glc aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

        \endgl\xe}{\exdisplay\footnotesize{Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification.} \xe}

    \swapboxes{\exdisplay\begingl
        \gla Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. //

        \glb aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

        \glc aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

        \endgl\xe}{\exdisplay\footnotesize{Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification.} \xe}

    \swapboxes{\exdisplay\begingl
        \gla Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. //

        \glb aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

        \glc aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

        \endgl\xe}{\exdisplay\footnotesize{Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification.} \xe}

    \swapboxes{\exdisplay\begingl
        \gla Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. Some non lipsum text to fill the gloss. //

        \glb aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

        \glc aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh aaaa bbbb cccc dddd eeee ffff gggg hhhh //

        \endgl\xe}{\exdisplay\footnotesize{Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification. Some text to demonstrate justification.} \xe}

\end{document}
```

[image]